# How much should the GPU is needed?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, torchvision

I am using V100 that has 32GB GRAM and 128GB RAM.

I made a network size of 2.5M weights, which takes 2 x (3,144,288) + 2 x (3,288,576) images as inputs. The batch size is 2. only 2.

This network keeps printing the error message : RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 1.90 GiB (GPU 0; 31.88 GiB total capacity; 24.91 GiB already allocated; 1.28 GiB free; 26.73 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)

I don't understand why it keeps saying that I'm lack of memory, since I used 15M-weights model with 16x(6,1000,1200) without any problem.

Or is there any way to load the inputs in RAM and model in GRAM but I am not aware of it ? If there is, please tell me how and thank you very much.

My pseudo-code for loading model is :

```
train_load, val_load = SRD.load_sr_st_dataset(route_img,route_dpt,bs=batch_size)
#print(train_load.dataset.__sizeof__())
sr_stereo = SRD.sr_stereo(max_d=192,bs=batch_size).cuda()
```

And for loading data is :

```
def parsedata(loaded_data,split):
    l10,l20,r10,r20,depth = loaded_data['l10'],loaded_data['l20'],loaded_data['r10'],loaded_data['r20'],loaded_data['depth']
    #print('l10',l10.shape)
    l10_v = A.Variable(l10.cuda())
    l20_v = A.Variable(l20.cuda())
    r10_v = A.Variable(r10.cuda())
    r20_v = A.Variable(r20.cuda())
    depth_v = A.Variable(depth.cuda())
    return l10_v,l20_v,r10_v,r20_v,depth_v
```

Comment: How big is the entire dataset and are how are you loading it in? I suspect that it is bigger than your RAM size.

Comment: @yudhiesh The whole size of dataset is about 100GB and I use dataloader to parse the dataset

Comment: What are your results for this? `mem = psutil.virtual_memory() print("Total RAM (GB): ", mem.total/1024/1024)`. It will tell you the total memory available.

Comment: Does it run out of memory in the first iteration or after some iterations?

Comment: @hkchengrex in the first iteration